# Field repository in *** required a bean of type *** that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Sorry, I'm new to Spring,
So I plan to connect to database using JPA
Here's my folder directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RBPg.png)
here's the `pom.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>CoursearnsSpring</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The run file:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.CoursearnsSpring.repository")
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository repository; 
    
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(repository.findAll());
    }
}
```

and the repository

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {
}
```

The model.Course:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String name;
    String description;
    String teacher_id;//the creators
    String admin_id;//the approvals
    String header;
    String tags;
    String displayname;//name of said user
```

the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Coursearn
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

when I tried to run, it always got the error:
`Field repository in com.example.CoursearnsSpring.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.CoursearnsSpring.repository.CourseRepository' that could not be found.`

Even though I using `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.CoursearnsSpring.repository")` to make sure it can scan the right directory, the same error still occurs

Comment: Have you already tried using the `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = CourseRepository.class)` annotation?

Comment: You shouldn't need the scan -- it already scans from the package holding your app on down. Why is the Exclude thing there? I see you have both spring jdbc and spring jpa. Are you sure you need both? I only ever include jpa.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm back after 2 hours, I don't know why I tumble across this errors anymore but I know how to fix, so that someone stuck here like me could possibly seeing the lies inside the line of code that may looks prettier than what it is
(All of these are done in application.properties)

- 1, Adding encrypt/trust certificate onto the sql link
- 2,Adding the driver for SQL
- 3, Adding SQL dialect 2012
- 4, Those things can also caused the errors of beans that could not be found, so don't panic and shuffle everythings up